# Qual a diferença entre "this" e "$scope"?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

No `AngularJS` utilizamos `$scope` para compartilhar informação entre os domínios de um `controller`. Existe também a sintaxe `Controller as` que permite que utilizemos o `this` para o mesmo fim.

1. Com `$scope`:

   ```
   function MeuController($scope) {
     $scope.mensagem;
   }

   <div ng-controller='MeuController'>
     {{mensagem}}
   </div>
   ```
2. Com `this`:

   ```
   function MeuController() {
     this.mensagem;
   }

   <div ng-controller='MeuController as vm'>
     {{vm.mensagem}}
   </div>
   ```

Qual a diferença entre as duas abordagens e quando devo utilizar cada uma delas?

Comment: Já existe um tópico igual so que em inglês.... O motivo de criar isto é so para aumentar a reputação?
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11605917/this-vs-scope-in-angularjs-controllers

Comment: @djva o motivo de criar é para termos conteúdo em português, afinal este é o StackOverflow **em Português**. Caso contrário não haveria a necessidade da existência deste site, já que a maioria das perguntas já foi respondida lá. Segue [aqui](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/5101/59479) uma resposta que esclarece um pouco mais a sua dúvida.

Comment: Então se o sentido é traduzir, fazemos plagio de conteúdos e traduzimos eles?

Comment: @djava Segue a definição de [plágio](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pl%C3%A1gio). Não vejo como uma pergunta pode ser uma propriedade intelectual, ainda mais considerando públicos diferentes. Também não consigo entender porque alguém como você, que possui os conhecimentos necessários para realizar uma pesquisa em inglês, participaria em um fórum em português, já que praticamente todas as respostas já estão disponíveis em outra língua. E quanto ao seu comentário, fique a vontade para abrir uma pergunta no [meta](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/) que é destinado a dúvidas deste tipo.

Comment: Tradução é legal com moderação @djva, o gerente da nossa comunidade [esclareceu](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/11/tradu%c3%a7%c3%a3o-de-perguntas-e-faqs) isso uma vez já..

Comment: Sempre que tiver algum questionamento quanto a alguma conduta, é bom ver o meta, pra ver o que a comunidade pensa.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Basicamente, tanto o uso de `$scope` como o `this` em angular tem como finalidade entre compartilhar as informações entre `view` e `controller`.

A diferença é que, quando se usa `this`, você precisa usar um alias para o controller na sua `view`.

Por exemplo:

```
<div ng-controller="MeuController as meu"></div>
```

A grande vantagem que vejo ao utilizar o `this`, é que se você tiver vários controllers dentro do outro, e em algum momento precisar de nomear variáveis com o mesmo nome, esse alias atuará como um `namespace` que separará os valores.

**Nota**: Quando se usa `this` sem o `as` na view (definição do alias), você poderá acessar as informações através da variável `$ctrl` (pelo menos é assim que funciona na [definição de componentes](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/component#creating-and-configuring-a-component)).

Já no caso do `$scope` você poderá definir as suas variáveis, sendo possível acessá-las imediatamente, sem necessidade de um "prefixo" como no caso acima.

Nota-se que em alguns casos, você precisará do `$scope`, mesmo utilizando o `this`. Por exemplo, em caso de uma definição de um `watcher` manualmente.

```
controller('MeuController', function ($scope) {

    var vm = this;

    vm.name = 'Wallace';


    $scope.$watcher('vm.name', function () {

        vm.first_name = name.split(' ')[0];
    })
})
```

Sem contar que, entre outras informações, o `$scope` contém informações especiais como por exemplo o `$parent`, que referencia o controller pai do controller atual.

Answer (score 0):

"$scope", é uma variável especial do angular, que possui os dados do contexto do controller.

"this" é uma palavra reservada do javascript, que sempre aponta pro objeto onde o método está executando, se o método estiver no controller do angular, ele estará referenciando o controller.

Comment: Ok, correto, mas não foi isso que ele perguntou. Tem como trabalhar a resposta pra responder o que foi perguntado?

Comment: -1. Isso não responde ao que foi perguntado.